# Problem using variable argument list and string formating

Tags: c++

I have the following function that accepts a string and a list of arguments, the idea is that it works as a printf for the user. The function below is a minimal executable example of the function.

```cpp
string description = "";

void error(string format, ...){
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    va_list arg_copy;
    va_copy(arg_copy, arguments);

    const int32_t size = snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), arguments) + 1;
    const unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = make_unique<char[]>(size);
    va_end(arguments);

    snprintf(buffer.get(), size, format.c_str(), arg_copy);
    va_end(arg_copy);

    description += string(buffer.get(), buffer.get() + size - 1);
}
```

And I call it as follows.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a = 123;
    error("Format %d", a);
    cout<< description;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is: Format 123

The output result is (the number changes each execution): Format 378812424

I guess it is some problem with the memory but I am not able to discover where the problem is.

Comment: You really should use a C++-style variadic template function instead of a C-style variadic function. Or better, consider using `std::ostringstream` or `std::format()` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `vsnprintf` rather than `snprintf` in this particular case?

Comment: My compiler does not supor std::format()

Comment: @PredaWnia for compilers that don't implement `std::format()` natively yet, you can use https://fmt.dev instead.

Comment: @PredaWnia This is a Q&A site. Please do not edit your questions to add solutions to them. That is what answers are meant for instead. If you want to [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), you can do that. Otherwise, upvote/accept an existing answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong print function.  By using `snprintf()`, you are printing the address of the `va_list` itself, not the values that it refers to.

To print a `va_list`, you need to use `vsnprintf()` instead, eg:

```
string description = "";

void error(string format, ...){
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);

    va_list arg_copy;
    va_copy(arg_copy, arguments);
    const int32_t size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), arg_copy) + 1;
    va_end(arg_copy);

    vector<char> buffer(size);

    vsnprintf(buffer.data(), size, format.c_str(), arguments);
    va_end(arguments);

    description.append(buffer.data(), size - 1);
}
```